# What determines if a pair of properties/variables have an uncertainty relationship?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

One of the most common definitions of the Uncertainty Principle is that it states one cannot measure both the position and momentum of a particle to a "perfect" accuracy (probably not the most rigorous but it's what I can gather off the top of my head). If the certainty of position increases, the certainty of momentum decreases, and vice-versa. I imagine it's commonplace because it's easy to explain, but further research into it gives examples of the Uncertainty Principle that aren't covered by this "layman's" definition, or at least not at first glance. And these competing definitions and explanations make it very difficult to make coherent sense of the Uncertainty Principle for me, even though I know it's true.

For example, according to quantum fluctuation, there is an uncertainty relationship between energy and time, rather than position and momentum. Also when measuring resolution of time or space, increasing the temporal resolution comes at the cost of reducing the spatial resolution and vice versa, [which also has to do with the Uncertainty Principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_resolution)

So one of two things sticks out to me. Either **1.** the common definition is just using position and momentum as easy-to-use examples, and really could be any 2 variables, or **2.** the cases of position/momentum, energy/time, and temporal/spatial resolution are actually all one and the same and can be reduced to the "position/momentum" relationship.

**If it is the first case**, then what exactly qualifies as a "property" of a particle, and what fundamentally makes two properties have an uncertainty relationship with each other? Could these relationships be different in another universe with different physics - i.e. in another universe energy and time no longer have an uncertainty relationship, but energy is "uncertainly tied up" with another property, like charge, spin, or velocity. Is it just how this universe ended up, or is there a logical/mathematical consequence that makes the idea of different uncertainty relationships as nonsensical as 2 + 2 = 5? Also, are all uncertainty relationships binary, or can there be systems of 3+ properties with uncertain relationships, where changing one changes the other N-1 properties?

**If it is the second case**, how can the relationship between energy and time be restated in terms of position/momentum? Likewise, how does the case of spatial vs. temporal resolution reduce to a tradeoff between position/momentum?

Comment: A pair of variables is related by the uncertainty principle if [the two variables are conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables). For more information on what this means [searching the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=conjugate+variables+uncertainty) would find lots of interesting questions.

Comment: @JohnRennie So only relationships between derivatives of action and the quantity with respect to which they differentiate have uncertainty relationships? How could the uncertainty relationship between spatial and temporal resolution be described in this way? I'm guessing it's a special case of the "time and frequency" example, with space replacing frequency somehow?

Comment: There isn't an uncertainty principle relating temporal and spatial resolution. These are not observables in QM i.e. not properties corresponding to a Hermitian operator.

Comment: @JohnRennie So is the Wikipedia article on temporal resolution I linked either wrong (wouldn't be surprised, it has no references) or I am heavily misunderstanding it?

Comment: I assume you mean the section titled *Physics*. This is not well written, but don't think it means temporal and spatial resolution are linked in the same way as position and momentum or energy and time.

Comment: @JohnRennie Ah okay. Thank you very much for clearing that up!

Comment: Look at this question and answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265117/uncertainty-and-classical-waves . The variables that are coupled in a HUP have to be related to each other through a fourier transform. (not to the dxdp).